# JavaScript cross domain scripting

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have 2 sub domains

```
passwordservices.example.com
computers.example.com
```

All computers are attached to the computers.example.com

A workstation called PC123456 on the domain has a fully qualified name is

```
PC123456.computers.example.com
```

The web pages are hosted on passwordservices.

How can I write a javascript that's hosted on PC123456
And access DOM elements on password services.

Comment: That's not exactly cross-domain if it's on the same domain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, JS believes that even a subdomain such as img.yourdomain.com is a different domain from www.yourdomain.com. Because of that, AJAX across pages from those two subdomains will not work. Also if you have an iframe from one to another, you will not be able to refence JS vars or functions back and forth.

A way around this involves setting up an iframe html on one domain and then calling that iframe from the page on the other subdomain. You have to set the document.domain to the same thing on both the parent page and its iframe, in order for them to talk to each other.

`document.domain = "yourdomain.com"`

[Source](http://www.tomhoppe.com/index.php/2008/03/cross-sub-domain-javascript-ajax-iframe-etc/): tomhoppe.com

You might also want to look into [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/)

Good Luck!!

Comment: A couple additional points of note: 1) you may only set `document.domain` once (per page). Some browsers will throw if you try to set it back or to something else. 2) Using `document.domain` is essentially painting yourself into a corner; you will likely be fine, but you **must** align it on **all** pages that need to communicate (even two on the same subdomain). All of that being said, it is the easiest solve here.

Comment: The domain with passwordservices dynamically generates html. The site is http://passwordservices.example.com/password.exe?… the parameters will determine the page output. I want to create an iframe to on the computer domain to perform data entry and assist my users to.change their password